# JPA: Specificaation api Cannot load entity by field from child class in JOINED inheritance

Tags: jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa, specifications, predicate, criteria-api

I have an abstract entity, extended multiple times, every child entity has own and repeated field
when I searching with parent fields this works, but when I passed child fields occurred error

```
employeeRepository.findAll(EmployeeSpecification.filterField(null,null,null),pageable).getContent();
```

Error 1

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: where near line 1, column 206 [select distinct generatedAlias0 from de.mexchange.packagingdb.entity.Employee as generatedAlias0 where exists (select distinct treat(generatedAlias0 as de.mexchange.packagingdb.entity.EmployeeThird) from  where treat(generatedAlias0 as de.mexchange.packagingdb.entity.EmployeeThird).other like :param0)]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:568)
```

Error 2

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [other] on this ManagedType
```

Comment: can you post the query and the entities?

Comment: I use specifiaction api

Comment: Subquery<EmployeeThird> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(EmployeeThird.class);
Root<EmployeeThird> subqueryRoot = subquery.from(EmployeeThird.class);
Expression custom = getExpression(subqueryRoot, "custom");
                criteriaQuery.multiselect(custom);
return criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.like(custom, "%1%"), subqueryRoot);